# Status of the Luna's conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, spherical-varieties

In the famous IHES paper <Variétés Sphériques de Type A> of D. Luna, he proposed a conjecture asserting that wonderful varieties of an adjoint semisimple group $G$ are bijective to spherical systems of $G$.

Luna himself solved this conjecture in loc. cit for groups of type A.

The uniqueness of this conjecture has been proven by Losev.

Many other sporadic cases are known, for instance, for simple-laced adjoint groups.

I find an old preprint "Wonderful Varieties: A geometrical realization" on arxiv. In this preprint, a proof of this conjecture is claimed. But this paper has not been published by far.

My question is:
Is Luna's conjecture still open? What is the precise status of the existence part of this conjecture?

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't work in anything related to the area, but here is what I could find. You can go through the articles that cite the preprint you mention on Google Scholar or another system. Browsing through some of the most recent ones you can see that the problem seems to still be unresolved and a few of them still refer to this preprint as a "proposal" to proving it.